# BPM and key detection for Android

Tags: android, music

I am looking for an Android application that can:

- perform BPM and key detection
- support MP3s

If possible, free.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rekordbox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pioneerdj.rekordbox&gl=US):

- free
- by Pioneer
- support MP3s and the most common music format
- BPM (1 decimal)
- key detection

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Anytune](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.anytune.musicplayer) works well for me

> Slow down music, choose the perfect pitch, and learn to play by ear!
> ANYTUNE™, the ultimate music practice app for musicians of all kinds,
> has been recreated for Android. Learn a song by slowing it down
> without changing the pitch. Pick out every note to learn a piece, or
> play along with your favorite tracks by starting slow and gradually
> increasing the tempo. Add marks to break down a song, color sections,
> and find your place quick. Create loops so you can practice parts over
> and over. Transpose a song to play or transcribe in a different key.
> Fine tune the song by cents for alternate and non-standard tunings.

[image]